# Make some elements of choice array readonly in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, python-3.6, django-modeladmin

I have a model:

```py
class myLimit(models.Model):
    limit = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(help_text="The upper limit of the number of points that can be used.")
    TYPES_OF_LIMITS = [('perday','Limit Per Day'),('lifetime', 'Lifetime Limit'),('peruser', 'Per User'),]
    limit_type = models.CharField(choices=TYPES_OF_LIMITS, max_length=20, default='lifetime')

    ...
```

I want to know how to disable (or make it read-only) the "peruser" ("Per User") choice/option. The current `myLimit` acts as a base model for an extended model which sets the default of `limit_type` to "peruser" and makes the entire thing read-only my using admin model's `exclude = ('limit_type',)`.

I set the default in the `save()` method of the extended model just before calling the super method. The main question remains: How to make a few choices read-only? I have read tutorials on making the entire field read-only, hiding it, and others but haven't figured out a way to make "only some choices" read-only.

Comment: When you say "readonly" do you mean to not display the option in the dropdown?

Comment: Yes. I want the admin to not be able to select that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom `ModelForm` for your model where you can overwrite your field to change the available choices

```
class mylimitForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        fields = ('limit', 'limit_type', ...)

    limit_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES_EXCLUDING_READONLY_ONES)
```

Then if you want to use this form in the admin you just have to set it in your `ModelAdmin`

```
class mylimitAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    form = mylimitForm
```

Comment: Did the job perfectly! Thank you.